# Grid View Dynamically Generated Column

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have Grid View which is dynamically binded with datatables.

I had to add in the  last column a command field AAddOn

When trying like below method..AAddOn is displayed at first..

How can we display the command field at the last..

```
  <asp:GridView ID="AGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true"  style="table-layout:fixed;" Width="2000px"   RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
               &nbsp;
           </EmptyDataTemplate>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ItemStyle-Width="80px" EditText="Edit Add On">
             <ItemStyle Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Small" />
              <HeaderStyle CssClass="AAddOn" />
             </asp:CommandField>
      </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For gridview, defined columns always render first then the auto generated columns render on the right side of it. To move auto generated columns to left side, you need **RowCreated** event. There you can manipulate the order of columns as required. You can use below code.

```
protected void AGridView_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e){
        List<TableCell> cellColumns = new List<TableCell>();
        foreach (DataControlField column in GridView1.Columns)
        {
            TableCell cell = e.Row.Cells[0];
            e.Row.Cells.Remove(cell);
            cellColumns.Add(cell);
        }

        e.Row.Cells.AddRange(cellColumns .ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution .